# Start Git Bash profile in Windows Terminal from bat file and pass in an executable command to run

Tags: command-line, bash, cmd.exe, git-bash, windows-terminal

I am trying to start 2 applications (client and server of a MERN stack app) in Git Bash using command-line arguments for Windows Terminal. Below given is my command

```
wt -M; new-tab -p "Git Bash" -d D:\ws\user-management\server cmd /k "npm run dev" ; split-pane -p "Git Bash" -H -d D:\ws\user-management\client cmd /k "npm run dev"
```

But this starts the application in windows cmd rather than in bash as I have given `cmd /k`. If I change the above command as `wt -M; new-tab -p "Git Bash" -d D:\ws\user-management\server npm run dev`, it throws this error

> [error 0x80070002 when launching `npm run dev']

How do I run my `npm run dev` from git bash itself rather than cmd